# Docker on Windows randomly crashes with 0xC0370106 when Dockerfile has too many commands

Tags: php, windows, iis, docker

We have a Dockerfile on microsoft/iis:10.0.14393.206 that runs IIS/PHP.

If we add too many commands the build starts to crash with this error:

> Container d6f3e9bd6f3e9bd6f3e9bd6f3e9b encountered an error during Start: failure in a Windows system call: The compute system exited unexpectedly. (0xC0370106)

If I run the same build command, it will work after a few tries.

I am running Docker version 17.06.0-rc4-ce-win15 (12573).
System: Windows 10 build 15063.413, 16 GB RAM, i5-6440HQ CPU 2.60 GHz

Is there a way to build a large Dockerfile without it crashing? Is this some type of limitation with Docker for windows?

Comment: This isn't a know issue. Try updating to the latest CE version. Docker 17.06CE is now stable. Also file an issue on https://github.com/docker/for-win